# How to match numbering of files across different folders e.g. rename NAME9.txt to NAME00009.txt

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a huge list of files, they came through different processes, so for some reason the ones in the first folder are numbered like this

`A9.txt A1.txt` while the ones in the other have `A00009.txt A.00001.txt`
I have no more than 99837 files so **only** four "extra" 0 on one side.

I need to rename all the files inside one folder so the names matches. Is there any way to do this in a loop? Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want all `.txt` files in a folder renamed so that the number part is always left-padded with zeroes to make it 5 digits wide in total?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I want both  folders to have identical names [they are not identical, but one is a translation of the other so they have to match to do an analysis downstream] so each file have to add 0 accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [`perl-rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) (Sometimes called `rename`) Not to be confused with [`rename` from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

```
perl-rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%05d", $&)/e' *.txt
```

The above script will rename all `.txt` files in a directory to the following:

```
A1.txt       -> A00001.txt
A10.txt      -> A00010.txt
Hello225.txt -> Hello00225.txt
```

[Test it Online](https://ideone.com/OnvtIX)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, but it's not to clear what OP really wants. Hopefully this will help them get started :-)

Comment: For anyone reading this who happens to be on OSX, you can install the tool mentioned with `homebrew`, using `brew install rename`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `perl-rename` is pretty cool, it will even create directories for you: `perl-rename 's~.*~a/b/c/$&~' *` <- Will move all files / directories into `a/b/c`

Comment: I was just studying its manpage actually - and it won't overwrite files if two come out to the same name - very nice.